# xamarin.forms nuget packages compatibility problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, nuget-package

When i try to use my xamarin.android project in my xamarin.forms solution(and in any new solution i open) i'm getting "nuget package compatibility" warnings and i can't acces my drawable folder located inside the resouces folder of my xamarin.android project(when i try to open it or put any files inside it shows a "System couldn't find the directed path" error).

The solutions i tried:

1. I made sure that all the nuget packages i use are compatible.
2. I tried to clean/rebuild the solution.
3. I tried to downgrade my nuget packages.
4. I tried to upgrade my minimum android version.

Here are all the warnings i'm getting for my "App4.Android" project:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

- Warning      Skipping
  App4.Droid.Resource.Id.design_menu_item_action_area. Please check
  that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Drawable.avd_show_password_1.
  Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Drawable.avd_hide_password_3.
  Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Drawable.avd_show_password_2.
  Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Drawable.avd_show_password_3.
  Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Drawable.avd_hide_password_1.
  Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Drawable.avd_hide_password_3.
  Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Drawable.avd_show_password_1.
  Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Drawable.avd_show_password_2.
  Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Drawable.avd_hide_password_2.
  Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Id.action_mode_bar. Please
  check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Drawable.avd_show_password_3.
  Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Drawable.avd_hide_password_2.
  Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.
- Warning      Skipping App4.Droid.Resource.Drawable.avd_hide_password_1.
  Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.

Comment: Delete the default folder `Drawable` ,then add a new folder and named it as `Drawable` .

Comment: Well, I think this is more of an issue with the ResourceDesginer.cs!? Delete it and re-add it!

Comment: Deleting the drawable folder and re-adding it worked it for me and since i'm in a bit of hurry to complete a project i'm working on i will go with that.Thank you for the suggestion @LucasZhang-MSFT .

Comment: I will try to take a look at the ResourceDesigner.cs file as soon as i have time @FreakyAli thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @denizkarlsefni .Glad it works ! I will post it as answer and can you accept it?Which will help more people .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT sure

Comment: You can accept it now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> System couldn't find the directed path

This error seems an existing issue of the IDE . And you just need to delete the default folder (in your case is **Drawable**) ,then create a new folder with the same name .